# How do I invert the y axis on Desmos?

Tags: math, graph, graphing, desmos

Does anyone know how to invert the y axis on desmos graphing calculator?

I am trying to invert it for my parabolic function
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8hxlvq8mhr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I contacted Desmos and they informed me that it currently isn't possible.  The best I can do is multiply all my y values by -1.